# Emulate a Linux terminal and shell commands on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, shell

Ok, I am accustomed to Linux/Unix like terminal and its commands and now I am using Windows. Does anyone know how to emulate a Linux terminal and the bash Commands?

Comment: Have you looked at cygwin?  part parts of the "terminal" are you looking to get access to?  Do you just want to have bash and the associated job control/gnu tools, or do you really like some features of xterms or gnome terminals or something else?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I do not know a unique software that do it perfectly, but, I know two awesome software (one for terminal emulator, another for shell commands) that can work together and do it perfectly.

[ConEmu (Linux Terminal Emulator for Windows)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) and [WinBash (Linux bash programs to Windows)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/)

## Preview

[image: ConEmu with win-bash]

### Setup it

1. Extract `conemu` in a directory (`C:/conemu`)
2. Extract `win-bash` files in a directory (`C:/winbash`)
3. Open `conemu` `C:/conemu/ConEmu.exe` or `C:/conemu/ConEmu64.exe`

   - 3.1 Go to menu, settings (Win + Alt + P)
     [image]
   - 3.2 Go to `Startup` menu
   - 3.3 Check `Command Line` item
   - 3.4 Put `C:/winbash/sh.exe` path 
     [image]
   - 3.5 Click in `Save Settings...`
   - 3.6 Close and reopen `conemu`

## Others shell libraries

You also can use any other shell libraries that you want, I personally use [Gt Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) instead `win-bash`, because `Git Bash` is the win-bash with some more commands like, `git` and `curl`, however, you can put in yours custom `.exe, .dlls etc.`  in `C:/winbash` folder.

- if you want to set it up with `Git Bash` instead `win-bash` install it and set the `$GIT_INSTALLATION_PATH/bin/sh.exe` in 3.4 step, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe` (for example) instead `C:/winbash/sh.exe`

Obs: I do not use the `git bash` instead `conemu` because `conemu` interaction is better in my opinion.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and I would vote for the Git Bash solution rather than the Win Bash one.